# How to get all the map tiles between two coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, openstreetmap

We created an app for offline maps, and i need to get the map tiles between the two coordinates for particular zoom level
I found a way to convert Coordinates to Map tiles
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers

Can anybody suggest a way to get these map tiles between two coordinates?

We are using OpenStreet Maps with iOS MapKit framework

EDIT:

I Recently found these two, they are providing pbf files, but i'm unable to find how to load it into a MKMapView

http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/bayern/oberbayern.html

http://extract.bbbike.org

Comment: Since you already linked to the page explaining how tile names are calculated where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: i want to get the tiles between the two coordinates, in between two coordinates there may be more tiles depends upon the distance of the two coordinates,
But i can only one per one coordinate